# Calling method on control in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently working with the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK .NET](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/%20*ArcGIS%20Runtime%20SDK%20for%20.NET*) where I'd like to have the current viewport of the map bound to a property on my view model. However, the view port (expressed as `Extent`) does not have a setter, despite being a dependency property.

In order to set the viewport, I need to call a method on the control. But how do I do that from the view model? I already found similiar questions here on SO, but most of them were answered with *The view model shouldn't be aware of the view.* I agree with that, but unfortunately I can't change the fact that the setter of a property on a proprietary control is a different method than the actual property I can bind to and read values from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do the job that might be considered MVVM friendly.
The one that I suggest is that you wrap your ArcGIS view in a custom control that you have full control over. This way you can expose your required dependency properties and handle their setters in your custom control.

I use this method almost every time I'm using a third-party component this way I make the component loosely coupled with my other code and I can replace them easily.

Comment: I wonder why I didn't even think about this. That's a fantastic idea, thank you.

Comment: It's generally considered ok to have View Events handled in code-behind, which instantly forwards the non-UI specific bits to your viewmodel, or you can use EventToCommand to skip that bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attached property to push make a VM request any listening view to go to a certain viewpoint. I'm using that in my sample here:

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-demos-dotnet/blob/master/src/TurnByTurn/RoutingSample.Shared/CommandBinder.cs

In your VM you simply raise INPC for a viewpoint:

```
public Viewpoint ViewpointRequested
{
    get { return m_ViewpointRequested; }
    private set
    {
        m_ViewpointRequested = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ViewpointRequested");
    }
}
```

And then lastly just bind this to the attached property on the MapView:

```
<esri:MapView Map="{Binding Map}"
             local:CommandBinder.RequestView="{Binding ViewpointRequested}" />
```